# Secondary email on Google account showing different name

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have an email that I'm using from within my gmail account and it is also my secondary email address for the same gmail account.

At some point in history, while I was setting up this email address for gmail, for some reason (I guess for testing), I typed my full name different; something silly.

After years, although I've changed it in within the gmail account settings as well as within the original webmail server settings; it still somehow shows this old typed trolling full name to people, who type my email address on their gmail accounts first time (and it stays so).

I feel that I'm becoming a victim of a dreary Google bug. How can I fix this otherwise? It seems definitely to be a cache issue somewhere on Google's servers...

Is there a solution to this?

Many thanks.

Comment: First, even if all name changes are correctly set, it may take time to be applied and shown in all Google services. And second, check Google account settings, and also Google+ page settings.

Comment: The issue has been there already for years. I already have checked all Google services and updated them years ago...